# How to Re-Order "Edit User" page fields in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, user-input

i want to Change order of Wordpress User Edit page fields in Admin side.

For Example::

Lats say below are the current order of fields:

- Username
- First name
- Last Name
- Nicname
- Password

Now, I want Password field After Username and before First Name

Thankx

Comment: The edit_user_profile hook is located in /wp-admin/user-edit.php

Comment: you can change the order over there